# Initializing pojo class with sub classes in one time

Tags: java

Is it possible to initialize class with it's sub-classes in one time instead of initialize each sub class by its own?
Example:

```
public class Abc {

    public Abc1 abc1;
    public Abc2 abc2 ;
    public Abc3 abc3;

    public static class Abc1 {
        public String id;
    }

    public static class Abc2 {
        public String organization;
    }

    public static class Abc3 {
        public String location;
    }
}
```

In order to be able to fill id, organization or location i need to manually initialize each sub-class like that:

```
Abc abc = new Abc();
abc.abc1= new Abc.Abc1();
abc.abc1.id = "123";

abc.abc2= new Abc.Abc2();
abc.abc2.organization = "Google"

abc.abc3= new Abc.Abc3();
abc.abc3.location = "New York";
```

If I will not initialize the sub-classes, I'll get null pointer exception when I will try to fill their attributes
Is there any trick to skip all that initializations in order to fill all the pojo attributes?

Comment: This is not subclasses but static inner classes. They have nothing to do with each other and static inner classes are purely an organisational concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Abc1`, `Abc2`, `Abc3` are not **sub-classes**, since they do not `extends Abc` class. Instead they are **inner** classes. In order to initialize them at once you can create a constructor in `Abc` which will also initialize those classes.

For example, constructor in `Abc` class:

```
    public Abc() {
        this.abc1 = new Abc1();
        this.abc2 = new Abc2();
        this.abc3 = new Abc3();
    }
```

Then you just need to initialize `Abc` class via this constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Abc abc = new Abc();

    abc.abc1.id = "123";
    abc.abc2.organization = "Google";
    abc.abc3.location = "New York";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **must** create the class objects via `new` somewhere, it won't be done automatically. But you can do it within the class `Abc` itself, rather than outside of the class.

For example, you can add field initializations to their declarations (see [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)):

```
public class Abc {

    public Abc1 abc1 = new Abc1();
    public Abc2 abc2 = new Abc2();
    public Abc3 abc3 = new Abc3();

    // ...

}

Abc abc = new Abc();
// abc.abc1, abc.abc2, abc.abc3 are already initialized

abc.abc1.id = "123";
abc.abc2.organization = "Google"
abc.abc3.location = "New York";
```

Or you may do this in constructor:

```
public class Abc {

    public Abc() {
        this.abc1 = new Abc1();
        this.abc2 = new Abc2();
        this.abc3 = new Abc3();
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers (which you should keep in mind when designing your classes / modeling your data), you could create a constructor that directly sets the values for the inner classes:

```java
public class Abc {

    public Abc(String id, String organization, String location) {
        this.abc1 = new Abc1();
        this.abc1.id = id;
        
        this.abc2 = new Abc2();
        this.abc2.organization = organization;
        
        this.abc3 = new Abc3();
        this.abc3.location = location;
    }

    public Abc1 abc1;
    public Abc2 abc2 ;
    public Abc3 abc3;

    public static class Abc1 {
        public String id;
    }

    public static class Abc2 {
        public String organization;
    }

    public static class Abc3 {
        public String location;
    }
}
```

And then just call:

```java
Abc abc = new Abc("123", "Google", "New York");
```